# Test http handlers in go echo

Tags: go, testing, echo

I am learning go echo and unit test and i am trapped into this and i am here to ask for help.

```
func TestGetGamesWithTags(t *testing.T){


    req := httptest.NewRequest("http.MethodGet", "/games?tags=tag0", nil)


    //response writer
    // we can inspect the ResponseRecorder output which is response generated by handler 
    recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
    GlobalTestServer.echo.ServeHTTP(recorder, request)

    // i dont know what to do after this

}
```

I dont know what to do after

```
GlobalTestServer.echo.ServeHTTP(recorder, request)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to test your `echo` handlers you need a bunch of things, the echo `context`,  `request`, `recorder`, here is an **example**:

```
import (
  "net/http"
  "net/http/httptest"
  "net/url"

  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestGetGamesWithTags(t *testing.T) {
    // Create an instance of Echo.
    e := echo.New() 
    // Create http test recorder
    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    // Add url params
    q := make(url.Values)
    q.Set("tags", "tag0")

    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/?"+q.Encode(), nil)
    // Create new echo context 
    c := e.NewContext(req, rec) 
    
    // Invoke your handlers against echo context
    assert.NoError(t, getGamesWithTags(c))
  
    require.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, rec.Code)
    assert.JSONEq(
       t,
       `{"key":"value"}`,
       rec.Body.String(),
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your response. I have multiple question in this. First, since getGamesWithTags has another function inside GetGamesByTags do we need to mock the function or just use it because there is also another unit test function to test GetGamesByTags

Comment: It depends on your buisness logic, you can do whenever you need.

Comment: from my view  you should test the http code and the response  body, I've show an example to assert all json response, but you can parse it and assert some key from the json response.

Comment: i am learning unit test and as per my knowledge it is recommended to write test for each task and avoid dependency if we do so it will be easier to know what is not working. I dont know if i am learning correct or not. I mean if this test case fail it should be error on GetGamesWithTags function only not on function which it is calling to retrive data from database. Am i right?

Comment: This kind of test are not unit it is an integration test.

Comment: i can see that rec.Body.String() return the returned response JSON body into string, is there anyway i can get it as JSON or anyway where i can check number of element returned. I googled it but i dont know if i dont know what to search or what, i can't get any help. Please

Comment: Hi @Philidor can you please help me on this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258274/http-post-request-unit-test-golang-echo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **unit test** your handler, good practice would be to mock the services you are using in the handler to isolate the handler function itself.

For example, you can use mockery to generate automatically mocks, and testify/mock to use them ; You can easily find more information about these searching on internet, for instance this one for introduction : https://medium.com/@thegalang/testing-in-go-mocking-mvc-using-testify-and-mockery-c25344a88691.